# Ajax post req of array item gives me a null response

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

As the title says, I can send a post request for a non array item using Vue Resource with no problem.

When it comes to sending an array data the response is a null array.Why is this happening?

```
submit:function(){
        var customizedExercises = this.customizedExercises;
        this.$http.post('/api/customized-exercises', customizedExercises).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            }, function(response){
            return response;
        })
    },


addSelectbox: function(){
        this.customizedExercises.push({ weight:'',sets_duration:'',name:'',reps:'',exercise_day_id:'' })
        }
    },
```

data

```
customizedExercises : [
{ weight:'',sets_duration:'',name:'',reps:'',exercise_day_id:'' }
],
```

html

```
<button type="submit" @click="addSelectbox">add select box</button>
<div v-for=" customizedExercise in customizedExercises" class="input-group">

<span class="input-group-addon">
<select class="selectpicker form-control"  v-model="customizedExercise.name"       name="name" id="name"> 
    <option value="{{ exercise.name }}" v-for="exercise in exercises">{{   exercise.name }}</option>
 </select> 
</span>

<span class="input-group-addon">
<select class="selectpicker form-control"  v-model="customizedExercise.sets_duration"  name="sets_duration" id ="sets_duration"> 
    <option v-for="number in numbers" value="{{number}}">{{number}}</option> 
</select> 
</span>

<span class="input-group-addon">
<select class="selectpicker form-control"  v-model="customizedExercise.weight"   name="weight" id="weight"> 
    <option v-for="number in numbers" value="{{number}}">{{number}}</option> 
</select>
```

{{number}}

```
<input type="hidden" name="exercise_day_id" v-model="customizedExercise.exercise_day_id" id="exercise_day_id" value="1" />
```

route

```
Route::post('/api/customized-exercises',function() {
$inputs = Request::json()->all();

return $inputs;


});
```

Comment: Did you convert the array of objects to JSON

Comment: `customizedExercises = JSON.stringify(this.customizedExercises);`

Comment: thank you I totally didn't know that:(

Comment: Does it work now, it works please select my answer so If any other person has the same issue they will see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the array of objects into a JSON before sending it over to PHP.

`customizedExercises = JSON.stringify(this.customizedExercises);`